# Textarea Counter in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script to count the number of letters in a textarea. Every message is 160 letters, so I am counting the text to see how many messages the user is making. I did this:

```
var msg = len / max;
```

but if he had like 170 letters I get 1.1 messages. I dont want to have anything like x.x, if it's 1.1 that means it's two messages. I want to make it 2 not 1.1.

How can I implement that?

```
 $('#msg').keyup(function () {
      var max = 10;
      var len = $(this).val().length;
      if (len >= max) {
        var msg = len / max ;
        $('#charNum').text(' you have Started a new Message , number of messages is ' + msg);
        $('#msgNum').text('you Created a New  Message');
      } else {
        var char = max - len;
        $('#charNum').text(char + ' characters left');
        $('#msgNum').text('1 Message');
      }
    });
```

Comment: @sweetamylase It's perfectly understandable even with a couple of typos.

Comment: It wasn't understandable 40secs ago...I was so confused. Glad he made the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of messages, ceil the floating point value you have

```
var msg = Math.ceil(len / max);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
Math.ceil(len / max);
```

it will give upper value.

if you use

```
Math.floor(len / max);
```

it will give lower value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var msg = Math.ceil(len / max);
```

which will round the result upward to it's nearest integer